# Where can I find a good example of a full asp.net website using best practices?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am looking to write a an asp.net website and would like a good project to use as a basis for getting started. Can someone help point me to some good examples where I can fully download and run the code?

Comment: Best practices are highly contextualized so I'm finding this question a little too vague to be of much use.

Comment: It's easier to find examples which are NOT using best practices. ASP.NET MVC Oxite (at least early versions of it) was a poor example. You can still learn from it by reading the critiques though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always check out the NerdDinner example for .NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2010/03/19/asp-net-performance-framework.aspx) is the ASP.NET Performance framework. Best practices regarding performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what is important to you, and provide a list with your question.

There are plenty of best practices sites using ASP.NET AJAX but a lot of SEO/Usability people would cringe if you showed it to them. ASP.NET MVC is architecturally a lot cleaner and includes a lot of best practices, but some people would argue that point quite strongly I'm sad to say. You need to try out a number of ASP.NET applications, and browse the best practices tag on this site.

I would personally use ASP.NET MVC for any new web application on the .NET platform. If I needed to I would then look for best practices scoped to that area.